# How do I stop my UICollectionViewCell shaking after a long pressure?

Tags: ios, animation, uicollectionviewcell

I'd like to make my UICollectionViewCell shaking after a long pressure (UILongPressGestureRecognizer) in order to delete an item.

I've read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189682/delete-cell-from-uicollectionview) and another [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025600/uicollectionviewcell-shake).

I succeeded to make my cells shaking by adding as suggested a method in my custom Cell class.

But how do I stop it after another long pressure ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554997/cancel-a-uiview-animation) :
I put this simple line in another method.

```
[self.layer removeAllAnimations];
```