# UICollectionView delete animation like iphone app

Tags: animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

i want to delete uicollectionview cell like apple iphone providing delete app from home screen

any one have idea or demo please help

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025600/uicollectionviewcell-shake ?

Comment: i want delete button and how to delete it

Comment: You add yourself a view for the delete button. How to delete a an item/cell from a UICollectionView, there are plenty of tutorial. At some point, you need to show what you've tried.

Comment: i have created a simple collectionview with 4 cell but here is what i want to do is add delete button cell layer not in it can it possible??