# UICollectionView Animation

Tags: swift, animation, uicollectionview

[image: Animation]

I've been trying to implement the following animation but without any luck. I can use a scroll view and insert elements as needed and when the user presses *Social* I can remove the other elements and insert new ones. But this whole thing screams UICollectionView to me, and with that I could have the entire share options scale if necessary without any kind of problem.

I've tried `performBatchUpdates` on `UICollectionView` and animate the `willDisplayCell`, and a custom `UICollectionViewFlow` but also no luck.

Does anyone have any tips about this? Is UICollectionView a bad idea, is it a good one, and if so any road you can point me to accomplish such animation?

Cheers

Comment: Seems like a "pagination" to me, with a little shake https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025600/uicollectionviewcell-shake ?

Comment: @Larme thank you. Not sure, it has more of a spring animation to it. Thank you